# Lie algebra action Whittaker model

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, hilbert-spaces

Let $(\pi, H)$ be an irreducible unitary generic representation of $G=\operatorname{GL}(r,\mathbb{C})$ and let $H^{\infty}$ be its subspace of smooth vectors. Let $W :G\to\mathbb{C} $ be the Whittaker model corresponding to a vector $v\in H^{\infty}$. We denote the matrix:

$$ a=\operatorname{diag}(a_1a_2...a_{r-1}, a_2a_3...a_{r-1},...,a_{r-2}a_{r-1},a_{r-1},1)\in\operatorname{GL}(r,\mathbb{C})$$ by $m(a_1,a_2,...,a_{r-1})$.

Prove that there exist $X_j$ and $Y_j$ in the lie algebra of $G$ such that:

$$ (X_j.W)(m(a_1,a_2,...,a_{r-1}))=a_jW(m(a_1,a_2,...,a_{r-1}))$$
$$ (Y_j.W)(m(a_1,a_2,...,a_{r-1}))=\bar{a_j}W(m(a_1,a_2,...,a_{r-1}))$$

for each $1\leq j\leq r-1$.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Crossposted on math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506474/lie-algebra-action-whittaker-model

Comment: How does the Lie algebra act on $\mathbb C$ here?

Comment: I meant the action on W, not on the complex plane.